# Rails: small controlles, implementing all logic inside models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote this code in controller:

```
def list
  @codes = Code.order("created_at")
  @languages = Language.order('name').collect {|l| [l.name, l.coderay]}
```

`@codes` is an array of posts. Each code has `language` field for `cpp` or `text` string. It contains coderay token.
`@languages` is array of programming languages in format `['C++', 'cpp'], ['Plain Text', 'text']`.
In other words, format of `Language` is `:name, :coderay`. I use it only in view to make select box.
So I use :coderay as primary key, but ruby added own PK `:id` to this model. And these models are not linked.

IDE writes me this warning:

> Controller action should call one model method other than an initial
>   find or new
>   This inspection warns if a controller
>   action contains more than one model method call, after the initial
>   .find or .new. It’s recommended that you implement all business logic
>   inside the model class, and use a single method to access it

What is a best solution to solve this problem?
1) Add 1-to-m link between `Codes` and `Language` and make `:coderay` PK.
2) Ignore this warning
3) Move `Language.order('name').collect {|l| [l.name, l.coderay]}` to view.

I think the best solution is (1), how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement option 1 to add a 1-to-1 link between your `Language` and `Code` by using a belongs to, and setting the foreign key.

code.rb

```
belongs_to :language, foreign_key: 'coderay', primary_key: 'language'
```

language.rb

```
has_many :codes, foreign_key: 'coderay', primary_key: 'language'
```

However if you want to load static data for a select box, I usually prefer to do that from a before_filter in the controller and pass it across to the view.

You might also like the `decent_exposure` gem. - https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure

Comment: Thanks, I have used before_filter.

Comment: @Yuri, Lets face it, the whole idea of passing instance variables around sucks.  By definition it's a breach of encapsulation.  Decent exposure is probably the most 'correct' way of doing it from a patterns and practices point of view, and a controller-per-resource point of view.

Comment: decent_exposure is very nice, but i am using it only for very simple controllers. Anyway if i need a single select on the page i prefer to do it in rails way).

Answer (score 2):

3 is the best in this case if u need it only for one select

```
select("post", "person_id", Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { :include_blank => true })
```

example from rails documentation

And don't create association that u don't need for your business logic.

Comment: Disagree.  That breaks the whole separation of concerns of MVC.  The Controller should be interacting with models to perform a query and should pass the results to a view.  The view should never interact directly with a model.

Comment: In the ideal world with unicorns and elfes thats true but in real world it's not.

Comment: I think this solution is not a good idea. It makes views do controller's job without any profit to us.

Comment: MVC is just a tool. And this approach is rails way one. Also it will be faster and u will need less test specs